# apache beam to mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-beam

I am trying to export the result of a pipeline to mongodb, the problem i have is that my to_mongo function receives an array ["122","sam"]. How can i convert this to an object to convert easily to a document for mongo

```
import apache_beam as beam

def to_mongo(item):
    """
    Uses the csv lib to escape everything correctly.
    """

    print(item)
    return {"ip": "133"}


class WriteToMongo(beam.PTransform):
    """
    Write to mongo
    """

    def expand(self, items):

        return (items | 'Convert format' >> beam.Map(
            to_mongo) | 'Write Output' >> beam.io.WriteToMongoDB(
            uri='mongo',
            db='test',
            coll='test'))
```

Comment: Can you give us a `mock` for the input `to_mongo` function and the expected result please ?

Comment: i was converting to an array earlier using a map hence why i got a weird format at the last stage

Comment: In the `to_mongo` function can you give me an example of input (maybe a Dict ?) and an example of expected output please ? I could help you more if a have examples and types of input and output for this method.